# Cannot write file in android internal storage

Tags: android, android-activity, filewriter, android-file

I am trying to create a text file in android internal storage but I am unable to do that. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 String append = "some data";
 try {

        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("fortify_profile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        fileout.write(append.getBytes());
        fileout.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not create Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Every where I looked same method has been given to create a file on android internal storage but
mine is not working. Please help

Comment: Description or code of openFileOutput method would be very helpful.

Comment: openFileOutput is a built in method provided by FIleOutputStream

Comment: Please show us how you check the existence of this file. "Not working" ? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and I hope that is creating file also. But you are not checking it in proper location. Go to `data>data>your_package_name>files>fortify_profile.txt` and that file should be there.